# Can a running process corrupt its executable and the files (currently in use) from its directory

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, executable

I have a running process started from a directory, let the executable name be foo.exe (windows), my doubt is can the process corrupt its own executable?

If so, will the next run not allow me to start the executable, or will the currently running executable display problematic behavior?
Similar doubts about some of the DLLs it may be using.

I am using windows, but answers both windows and linux appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows locks the executable while it is running, the .EXE cannot be edited nor renamed/deleted.

.DLL files are also read-only so they cannot be edited but they can be renamed so a evil program could perform a .DLL replacement attack.

Linux allows files to be `unlink`ed while they are in use so replacement attacks apply. I don't know if there is a way to edit them in place.

If the executable is on a network share these restrictions might not apply, it would depend on the server implementation and the protocol used.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the answer is NO—unless there is some bug in the operating system. The operating system will open the executable as read-only. Some operating system then use the executable as the page file for read-only sections of the process. It would be impossible to write back to the executable in the absence of a bug in most operating systems.